# Ai Tenchi Muyo! episode 59 ending song

Tags: tenchi-multiverse, ai-tenchi-muyo

Can anyone please tell me the title of the song that starts at 3:04 of episode 59? I love the way it sounds and I want to hear the full version, but since I can't read Japanese I can't find it.

Please and thank you very much for anyone that answers.

Comment: Please don't include links to illegal anime streaming website. The episode number and the timestamp are enough. Welcome to Anime & Manga SE.

Comment: Ahh sorry about that new to the site so didn't know that D:

Answer (score 1):

The song is titled **キミと見た花 キミと見た空** (*The flower I saw with you. The sky I saw with you*), according to the credit roll of the episode:

[image]

According to [the official website of Ai Tenchi Muyo](http://www.ai-tenchi.jp/bd_dvd_music/index.html), the full version of the song is included in the BD/DVD Volume 1, which is set to released on January 21st, 2015.

> ### 封入特典
>
> ### キャラクターソングCD壱
>
> - 愛してるって叫びましょ!! -full ver.-
>       歌:川流もも(CV:東山奈央)
> - キミのままで! -full ver.-
>       歌:ハチ子(CV:優木かな)、沙流葉七(CV:M・A・O)、笛山塔里(CV:深田愛衣)
> - キミと見た花 キミと見た空 -full ver.-
>       歌:川流もも(CV:東山奈央)、鬼ノ城紅(CV:大地葉)

Currently, the album **愛・天地無用エンディングテーマShort ver.集 Vol.1** [which includes the short version of the song](http://www.ai-tenchi.jp/bd_dvd_music/music.html) can be bought from [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E6%84%9B%E3%83%BB%E5%A4%A9%E5%9C%B0%E7%84%A1%E7%94%A8%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9EShort-ver-%E9%9B%86-Vol-1-%E5%B7%9D%E6%B5%81%E3%82%82%E3%82%82-%E9%AC%BC%E3%83%8E%E5%9F%8E%E7%B4%85/dp/B00OTWWUK8/ref=sr_1_1?s=dmusic&ie=UTF8&qid=1414718747&sr=1-1&keywords=%E6%84%9B%E3%83%BB%E5%A4%A9%E5%9C%B0%E7%84%A1%E7%94%A8), [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/jp/album/ai-tian-wu-yongendingutemashort/id930455509), among others.